# privateNetworkClientServer error when using geoserver with cesium

Tags: https, microsoft-edge, geoserver, cesiumjs, wms

I have a geoserver hosting imagery over http. my client site uses https. I've been using openlayers and it all works perfectly. now i'm trying to move to cesiumjs and i'm not getting any imagery in IE or Edge (i am unable to test other browsers unfortunately). i can get imagery in my client if using bing maps, so the client code is functional otherwise. from the browser console i see:

SEC7117: Network request to http://[myserver]:8080/geoserver/cite/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetMap&styles=&format=image%2Fjpeg&layers=cite%3Abmpyramid&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=195678.7924100496%2C156543.03392804041%2C234814.55089206248%2C195678.7924100496&width=256&height=256 did not succeed. This Internet Explorer instance does not have the following capabilities: privateNetworkClientServer

and:

SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by http://[myserver]:8080/geoserver/cite/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetMap&styles=&format=image%2Fjpeg&layers=cite%3Abmpyramid&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=195678.7924100496%2C195678.7924100496%2C215246.6716510579%2C215246.6716510579&width=256&height=256

the URLs are good; i can copy/paste into a new browser and get tiles back. from the browser network tab of the dev tools i can see there are no outgoing image requests.

does anybody know of a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the cryptic error messages, it seems this is not an HTTP/HTTPS issue like I  thought; it's a Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) problem specific to WebGL/CesiumJS. It is summarized near the bottom of this page: https://cesiumjs.org/tutorials/Imagery-Layers-Tutorial/ .

Basically there are two options. First, you can enable CORS in your geoserver. I confirmed this did indeed resolve the issue in my dev environment. However, this  is not really an option for us in prod.

The other option is to set up a proxy where instead of cesium directly requesting tiles, it  requests them from your own web server and your web server fetches them manually. when going this route, you modify your cesium like so:

```
layers.addImageryProvider(new Cesium.ArcGisMapServerImageryProvider({
    url : '//server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer',
    proxy : new Cesium.DefaultProxy('/proxy/')
}));
```